# HC 08 Module with Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, communication

I recently bought the HC 08 Bluetooth module (link [here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/SH-HC-08-CC2541-Bluetooth-4-0-BLE-to-UART-Transceiver-Module-with-Transparent-Serial-Port/32392960671.html)). As the specs state, this module supports Bluetooth 4.0 which indicates that it supports BLE (Bluetooth low energy).

My goal is to be able to use something similar to the CurieBLE library: I want to code services and characteristics on my Arduino so I can discover those on LightBlue (iOS).

I searched the internet for some guidelines, but I only found code using AT commands and honestly I don't know anything about those.

Can you please recommend any source to achieve the goal?

**Update**

After following the connections in this [link](http://www.prometec.net/bluetooth-le/) (In Spanish I guess but helpful), I was able to discover the Arduino on LightBlue. The characteristic name was Tx/Rx and I was able to write, read and subscribe to notifications (data coming in). Of course if would be better to find something that allows the definition of services and characteristics.